# Bug (or missed opportunity) in MarginalDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Observe:

```
dist = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[k, Range@5];
Tr@Range@5
MarginalDistribution[dist, {1}]
MarginalDistribution[dist, {1, 2}]
First@%
```

> 15
>
> TransformedDistribution[{[FormalX]},[FormalX][Distributed]HypergeometricDistribution[k,1,15]]
>
> MarginalDistribution[MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[k,{1,2,12}],{1,2}]
>
> MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[k,{1,2,12}]

Note that the single dimension marginal is correct (though a bit weird it's returned as a transformed distribution, vs just the Hypergeometric distribution).

Adding dimensions returns unevaluated. Yet, the *contents* within the head are correct.

I'd venture the optimizations made to this family of distributions in 10.x has something that slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica makes distinction between $X$ and $\{X\}$ by design:

```
dist = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[k, Range@5];
{MarginalDistribution[dist, {1}], MarginalDistribution[dist, 1]}
```

> {
>        TransformedDistribution[{[FormalX]}, 
>           [FormalX] [Distributed] HypergeometricDistribution[k, 1, 15]], 
>        HypergeometricDistribution[k, 1, 15]}

this is needed for internal consistency.

The marginal $1,2$ retains head `MarginalDistribution` because it can not be expressed through any simpler distribution. The marginal is 2D distribution, while `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[k, {1, 2, 12}]` is 3D distribution.

Comment: Are you commenting as either a Wolfram engineer that knows this as fact, or have an authoritative source to that effect ("...by design.")? Because in fact the contents *are* a simplified distribution, that can be used in any dimension <= the expression, e.g., `d = First@
  MarginalDistribution[
   MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[10, Range@5], {1, 2}];
Probability[x >= 1, {x} \[Distributed] d]` does precisely what's intended (and what the changes in this family exhibit when probability queries involve less than the whole set of categories).